# Two Apps Script projects with the same settings have different locales

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, date-formatting

I currently have two Google Apps Script projects. The first is bound to a standard Google Sheet. The second is bound to a Google Sheet which is the response sheet for a Google Form.

These two projects are creating documents, and placing them in folders according to a `Date` object, where I make the folder name by calling `date.toLocaleDateString()`.

My issue is that these two projects are creating folders with different formatting.

The first project creates folders like '26 April 2018', while the second project creates folders like 'April 26, 2018'.

When inside both spreadsheets, 'File' -> 'Spreadsheet settings...' tells me my locale is 'Australia', and timezone is 'GMT+10:00'.

When inside both projects, 'File' -> 'Project Properties' tells me my timezone is 'GMT+10:00'.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?? It is very frustrating and causing me all sorts of issues. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Below is some code I placed inside both projects' `onOpen()` method to demonstrate the output.

```js
var today = new Date();
console.log(today.toLocaleDateString());

// Script 1 prints "26 April 2018"
// Script 2 prints "April 26, 2018"

console.log(Session.getScriptTimeZone());

// Script 1 prints "Australia/Sydney"
// Script 2 prints "Australia/Sydney"
```

Comment: what is Session , where you define it or import it

Comment: @g33k `Session` is a Google Apps Script built-in class. @Ryan, consider using `Utilities.formatDate()`

Comment: @tehhowch `Utilities.formatDate()` does everything I need and more! So glad you found that for me. Thanks